# SqlBulkCopy approximate performance

Tags: c#, sql-server, http, sqlbulkcopy

I want to write a web api which should receive Excel / csv files with around 10 columns and parse and insert into a normalized SQL Server database using `SqlBulkCopy` (4 foreign key constraints, 2 non-clustered indexes).

What will be approximate achievable TPS (transaction per second) within default timeouts and with 8GB memory?

The upload operation will happen once in a while with approx 1 million records.

Comment: You can disable constraints, may give improved performance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried this scenario and able to achieve 6000 TPS without timeouts and memory overload.